# How to install lxml in Macbook Pro M1 Chip device?

Tags: odoo, lxml, apple-m1

I have been trying to install odoo framework in my laptop. But due to incompatinilty not able to install lxml

````
  File "/Users/ /Odoo/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/Users/ /Odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from . import modules
  File "/Users/ /Odoo/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "/Users/ /Odoo/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 10, in <module>
    import odoo.tools as tools
  File "/Users/ /Odoo/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import _monkeypatches
  File "/Users/ /Odoo/odoo/tools/_monkeypatches.py", line 6, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))```
````

Answer (score 0):

What method do you follow to install odoo? I think it is something that has to do with your python version as well.

However, you can build `lxml` from its source: https://github.com/lxml/lxml checkout to the following branch `lxml-4.9.1` then

```
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
cd dist/
sudo pip3 install lxml-4.9.1-cp310-cp310-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl
```

Comment: I am installing through terminal in pycharm. I am getting this error ```ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/usr/odoo/lxml-4.9.1-cp310-cp310-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl'
```

Comment: @PeakyBlinder well you should try with `sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt` that's why the requirements file is there

Comment: I tried to install requirements.txt. All the packages are installed successfully, including lxml. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @PeakyBlinder is it M1 monetary? also you can try reinstalling the library and then try to run odoo
`pip uninstall lxml` then 
`ARCHFLAGS="-arch arm64" pip install lxml --compile --no-cache-dir`

Comment: Yeah, I am using M1 monetary. Tried the above command. The lxml package is successfully installed actually. Yet, I am still getting the import error.

Comment: @PeakyBlinder the best way to install odoo on M1 is by installing all required libraries that are in the documentation, then pull the repository from github and install all the requirements if it doesn't work you may need to build `setup.py`

Comment: I solved the issue by downgrading the version to python3.8. Not really sure what worked. Thank you.

Comment: @PeakyBlinder I already mentioned in my answer: `I think it is something that has to do with your python version as well.` by the order of the peaky blinders!

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I am new to development. Another lesson learned. :D